# Logstash override host with filebeat name

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, filebeat

I have setup the `FileBeat -> Logstash -> ElasticSearch -> Kibana` set-up successfully. Now in logstash I want to override the `host` with the `beat.name`. However, When I try to refer to the beat metadata, the variable is not resolved.

```
    mutate {
        add_field => {
            "timestamp" => "%{year}-%{month}-%{day} %{time}"
        }
        replace_field => {
            "host" => "%{[@metadata][beat][name]}"
        }
    }
```

I think I am missing some major configuration. Even when `Logstash` forwards it to `elasticsearch`, these symbol resolution are not done.

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
  }
```

How do we refer to filebeat meta information in logstash config file correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `beat.name` field is not carried in the `@metadata` object. `beat` is a top-level field in the event. So to refer to the value use `[beat][name]` or in string use `"%{[beat][name]}"`.